# how to set google sheet title via api?

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-sheets-api

good day

Using this code, I'm able to create a spreadsheet. It will return an object containing the spreadsheet Id

```
            Dim service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With
            {
                .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
            })

        Dim requestBody = New Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet()

        Dim request = service.Spreadsheets.Create(requestBody)

        Dim r = request.Execute()

        Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r))
```

My question is, how do I set a title to the sheet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is the way to update a spreadsheet title

        Dim bur = New BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
        bur.Requests = New List(Of Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request)

            Dim sheetprop = New SpreadsheetProperties
        sheetprop.Title = "my new title"

        Dim britem = New Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request
        britem.UpdateSpreadsheetProperties = New UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest With {.Properties = sheetprop}
        britem.UpdateSpreadsheetProperties.Fields = "Title"

        bur.Requests.Add(britem)

        Dim brequest = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(bur, r.SpreadsheetId)

        Dim resp = brequest.Execute()
```